# Разные формы слов-названий разделов в "Активность/Голоса"

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

Слова-названия разделов в "Активность/Голоса" (ссылки не привожу, т. к. каждый участник может видеть только свою такую страницу, а ссылки на них у всех разные) почему-то имеют разные формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слово "Переоткрыть" стоит не в такой форме, как остальные ("Удаление", "Восстановление", "Закрытие").

Нужно - "Переоткрытие".

Хотя, по-моему, здесь уж лучше было бы что-то вроде "Голоса за Переоткрытие" или "За переоткрытие".

Comment: У вас нет 3к, но есть колонка "переоткрыть"?

Comment: @Зонтик, они всегда и у всех есть. Просто там пусто. А у вас нет что ли?

Comment: А... Это на вкладке "голоса". А я искал во вкладке "все действия".

Comment: Вместо слеша в заголовке, по-моему, лучше стрелку "->" поставить. Слеш — это когда "или". Хотя может я придираюсь)

Comment: Ссылки на профиль можно делать универсальными для залогиненного юзера. Вот [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes). Не всегда работает, но довольно часто.